# Can TypeScript class read SystemJS class?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

Can TypeScript read/get SystemJS and use it?

This is javascript version

```
    System.config({
        baseURL: "/lib",
        defaultJSExtensions: true
    });
    System.import('/scripts/angular2-demo/Main');
```

This is typescript version.  It said it can't find `System` so obviously I need to declare something or import it.

```
class SignInPage {
    constructor() {
        System.config({
            baseURL: "/lib",
            defaultJSExtensions: true
        });
        System.import('/scripts/angular2-demo/Main');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `declare var System: any;` at the top of your file. This tells TypeScript that there exists some variable named `System` that is of type any.

There is also a [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) definition file you can install with [Typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings), so you can get auto-completion with it.

Comment: Ah!  That's a start.  Oddly, I found one at GitHub at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/systemjs/systemjs.d.ts   So, not sure how exactly to use it in VS2015.  I tried package.json but there is no "definitely-typed" part for System.  :-/  This is a little confusing.

Comment: I linked to the typings page in my answer. It is a tool that will install the type definition file for you. Once you have typings installed, run the command `typings install react --ambient --save` to install the definition file.

Comment: Got it.  Ran this `typings install systemjs --ambient --save` and I now see this `systemjs` in typings.json.